# Multiplication of two double-digit integer with arrays in Fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, gfortran, multiplication, fortran95

I have tried to write a code for multiplying two double-digit integers like *ab * cd* using arrays and the preliminary multiplying method. However, when I compile my code and insert any input, the output is a wrong result. I traced my code and I got an appropriate result but in compiling is something different. for example i insert 9 9 9 9 which mean 99 * 99 in this code but the result is 1210 instead of 9801.

```
program main
    ! multiplication of two double-digit integer ! array method
  implicit none
  integer , parameter :: size=2
  integer , dimension (size)::A
  integer , dimension (size)::B
  integer , dimension (size+1)::C
  integer , dimension (size+2)::D
  integer , dimension (size+2)::E
  integer :: i=0,carry1=0,carry2=0,carry3=0

  do i=1,size,1
    read *,A(i)
  end do
  do i=1,size,1
    read *,B(i)
  end do
  do i= 3,2,-1
        C(i)=B(size)*A(i-1)+carry1
        if (C(i)>9)then
            C(i)=mod (C(i),10)
            carry1 = C(i)/10
            else
            carry1=0
        end if
    end do
    C(1)=carry1

    D(4)=0

    do i=3,2,-1
            D(i)=B(size-1)*A(i-1)+carry2
            if (D(i)>9)then
                D(i)=mod (D(i),10)
                carry2= D(i)/10
                else
                carry2=0
            end if
    end do

  D(1)=carry2

  do i=4,2,-1
    E(i)=D(i)+C(i-1)+carry3
    if (E(i)>9) then
        E(i)=mod (E(i),10)
        carry3=1
        else
        carry3=0
    end if
  end do
  E(1)=D(1)+carry3

  do i=4,1,-1
    print*,E(i)
  end do

end program main
```

Comment: Welcome, be sure to take the Welcome [tour]. Please show us your results and tell us which reults you expect instead.

Comment: Thanks. for example i insert  9 9 9 9  which mean 99 * 99 in this code but the result is 1210 instead of 9801.

Comment: [Edit] your question to include important information, do not use comments.

Comment: Consider, carefully, the value that `C(i)` has when the statement `carry1 = C(i)/10` is first evaluated.